# How to override WordPress Plugin class method

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin which class is something like that:

```
<?php

namespace myPro\EventCalendarPro;

use WP_Widget;

/**
 * Adds ECP_Widget widget.
 */

class ECP_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    public function widget () {

    }
}

?>
```

Now, how can I override the widget method from my theme **functions.php** file?

Answer (score 0):

> The simple answer to this question is "You cannot do this".

Because in PHP you cannot redefine classes, methods, and functions. But you can use **PHP Runkit** extension to redefine your methods

Runkit function to *redefine* method is `runkit_method_redefine`

### Code Example

```php
<?php
class Example {
    function foo() {
        return "foo!\n";
    }
}

// create an Example object
$e = new Example();

// output Example::foo() (before redefine)
echo "Before: " . $e->foo();

// Redefine the 'foo' method
runkit_method_redefine(
    'Example',
    'foo',
    '',
    'return "bar!\n";',
    RUNKIT_ACC_PUBLIC
);

// output Example::foo() (after redefine)
echo "After: " . $e->foo();
?>
```

But for first you should install the `php-runkit` extension on your server.

[How to install Runkit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/runkit.installation.php)